# How to apply Gaussian filter to DFT output in OpenCV

Tags: image, opencv, fft, gaussian, dft

I want to create a Gaussian high-pass filter after determining the correct padding size (e.g., if image width and height is 10X10, then should be 20X20).

I have Matlab code that I am trying to port in OpenCV, but I am having difficulty properly porting it. My Matlab code is show below:

```
f1_seg = imread('thumb1-small-test.jpg');

Iori = f1_seg;


% Iori = imresize(Iori, 0.2);

%Convert to grayscale
I = Iori;
if length(size(I)) == 3
    I = rgb2gray(Iori);
end
% 

%Determine good padding for Fourier transform

PQ = paddedsize(size(I));

I = double(I);

%Create a Gaussian Highpass filter 5% the width of the Fourier transform

D0 = 0.05*PQ(1);

H = hpfilter('gaussian', PQ(1), PQ(2), D0);

% Calculate the discrete Fourier transform of the image.

F=fft2(double(I),size(H,1),size(H,2));

% Apply the highpass filter to the Fourier spectrum of the image

HPFS_I = H.*F;
```

I know how to use the DFT in OpenCV, and I am able to generate its image, but I am not sure how to create the Gaussian filter. Please guide me to how I can create a high-pass Gaussian filter as is shown above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe where you are stuck is that the Gaussian filter supplied by OpenCV is created in the spatial (time) domain, but you want the filter in the frequency domain. [Here](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/imagefilter/) is a nice article on the difference between high and low-pass filtering in the frequency domain.

Once you have a good understanding of how frequency domain filtering works, then you are ready to try to create a Gaussian Filter in the frequency domain. [Here](http://vision.yeditepe.edu.tr/EE562/files/EE469_4.pdf) is a good lecture on creating a few different (including Gaussian) filters in the frequency domain.

<strike>If you are still having difficulty, I will try to update my post with an example a bit later!</strike>

**EDIT :**
Here is a short example that I wrote on implementing a Gaussian high-pass filter (based on the lecture I pointed you to):

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

double pixelDistance(double u, double v)
{
    return cv::sqrt(u*u + v*v);
}

double gaussianCoeff(double u, double v, double d0)
{
    double d = pixelDistance(u, v);
    return 1.0 - cv::exp((-d*d) / (2*d0*d0));
}

cv::Mat createGaussianHighPassFilter(cv::Size size, double cutoffInPixels)
{
    Mat ghpf(size, CV_64F);

    cv::Point center(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    for(int u = 0; u < ghpf.rows; u++)
    {
        for(int v = 0; v < ghpf.cols; v++)
        {
            ghpf.at<double>(u, v) = gaussianCoeff(u - center.y, v - center.x, cutoffInPixels);
        }
    }

    return ghpf;
}


int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/)
{
    Mat ghpf = createGaussianHighPassFilter(Size(128, 128), 16.0);

    imshow("ghpf", ghpf);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

This is definitely not an optimized filter generator by any means, but I tried to keep it simple and straight forward to ease understanding :) Anyway, this code displays the following filter:

[image]

**NOTE :** This filter is not FFT shifted (i.e., this filter works when the DC is placed in the center instead of the upper-left corner). See the OpenCV [dft.cpp](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/dft.cpp) sample (lines 62 - 74 in particular) on how to perform FFT shifting in OpenCV.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the answer i am thinking i am very near to the result by your excellent guidance but I am not sure how can i produce the filter like this one which is produced in matlab...
[EDIT] http://uploading.com/files/498a6e9b/filter.png/

Comment: this one is the output from matlab ... does it mean i need to create 4 different planes for this type of filter and merge all of them?
http://i44.tinypic.com/r0twf7.png

Comment: Actually, what is occurring there is that the filter has been shifted using `fftshift` in Matlab. As described in the first article I mentioned this, swaps quadrants 1 <-> 4 and 2 <-> 3. Also, I believe the `dft.cpp` OpenCV sample shows how to do this.

Comment: mevatron  thanks a lots , you have saved my day and by using quads i am able to rearrange them according to the matlab displayed filter.

Comment: There is another question if you have time please share some tips there as well... many thanks!
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646652/dft-to-spatial-domain-in-opencv-is-not-working

Comment: I've tried to filter my image with the filter you gave, but I'm getting the same as doing a `blur` instead (even when I'm applying it to a DFT matrix using `filter2D`). Do you know what am I doing wrong?