# DFT to spatial domain in OpenCV is not working

Tags: c++, opencv, dns, spatial, dft

I have created dft of an image and after some adjustment with filters i want to convert it back to the real image but every time when i do that it gives me wrong result ..seems like its not converting it back.
`ForierTransform` and `createGaussianHighPassFilter` are my own functions rest of the code i am using like below for the inversion back to real image.

```
Mat fft = ForierTransform(HeightPadded,WidthPadded);
Mat ghpf = createGaussianHighPassFilter(Size(WidthPadded, HeightPadded), db);
Mat res;
cv::multiply(fft,ghpf,res);
imshow("fftXhighpass1", res);
idft(res,res,DFT_INVERSE,res.rows);
cv::Mat croped = res(cv::Rect(0, 0, img.cols,img.rows));

//res.convertTo(res,CV_32S);
imshow("fftXhighpass", res);
```

even if i dont apply the filter  i am unable to reverse back dft result ...
here is my dft code is , i could not find any sample to reverse dft back to normal image..

```
Mat ForierTransform(int M,int N)
{
    Mat img = imread("thumb1-small-test.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat padded;
    copyMakeBorder(img, padded, 0, M - img.rows, 0, N - img.cols, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar::all(0));

    Mat planes[] = {Mat_<float>(padded), Mat::zeros(padded.size(), CV_32F)};
    Mat complexImg;
    merge(planes, 2, complexImg);

    dft(complexImg, complexImg);


    split(complexImg, planes);
    magnitude(planes[0], planes[1], planes[0]);
    Mat mag = planes[0];
    mag += Scalar::all(1);
    log(mag, mag);

        // crop the spectrum, if it has an odd number of rows or columns
    mag = mag(Rect(0, 0, mag.cols & -2, mag.rows & -2));


    normalize(mag, mag, 0, 1, CV_MINMAX);
    return mag;
}
```

kindly help

[EDIT: After I found the solution with the help of mevatron] (below is the correct code)

```
 Mat ForierTransform(int M,int N)
{
    Mat img = imread("thumb1-small-test.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat padded;
    copyMakeBorder(img, padded, 0, M - img.rows, 0, N - img.cols, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar::all(0));

    Mat planes[] = {Mat_<float>(padded), Mat::zeros(padded.size(), CV_32F)};
    Mat complexImg;
    merge(planes, 2, complexImg);

    dft(complexImg, complexImg);

    return complexImg;
}

Mat img = imread("thumb1-small-test.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
int WidthPadded=0,HeightPadded=0;
WidthPadded=img.cols*2;
HeightPadded=img.rows*2;
int M = getOptimalDFTSize( img.rows );
//Create a Gaussian Highpass filter 5% the height of the Fourier transform
double db  = 0.05 * HeightPadded;


Mat fft = ForierTransform(HeightPadded,WidthPadded);
Mat ghpf = createGaussianHighPassFilter(Size(WidthPadded, HeightPadded), db);
Mat res;

cv::mulSpectrums(fft,ghpf,res,DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);


idft(res,res,DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT,img.rows);

Mat padded;
copyMakeBorder(img, padded, 0, img.rows, 0, img.cols, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar::all(0));
Mat planes[] = {Mat_<float>(padded), Mat::zeros(padded.size(), CV_32F)};
split(res, planes);
magnitude(planes[0], planes[1], planes[0]);
Mat mag = planes[0];
mag += Scalar::all(1);
log(mag, mag);

// crop the spectrum, if it has an odd number of rows or columns
mag = mag(Rect(0, 0, mag.cols & -2, mag.rows & -2));

int cx = mag.cols/2;
int cy = mag.rows/2;

normalize(mag, mag, 1, 0, CV_MINMAX);

cv::Mat croped = mag(cv::Rect(cx, cy, img.cols,img.rows));
cv::threshold(croped , croped , 0.56, 1, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

imshow("fftPLUShpf", mag);
imshow("cropedBinary", croped);
```

It now can able to display ridges valley of finger , and can be more optimize with respect to threshold as well

Comment: guys please help me out from this ....i have tried some tests by changing the code in ForierTransform function i have returned the planes element 1 like below. Doing this get me the real pic but it is very large faint and with very bad look.. I have just returned the Planes[1] instead of further below calculation of 
ForierTransform(int M,int N) function. e.g. after         magnitude(planes[0], planes[1], planes[0]);
return planes[1];

Comment: on the conversion side i have added few more code 
idft(res,res,DFT_INVERSE + DFT_SCALE,img.rows);

Mat padded;
    copyMakeBorder(img, padded, 0, img.rows, 0, img.cols, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar::all(0));
     Mat planes[] = {Mat_<float>(padded), Mat::zeros(padded.size(), CV_32F)};
    split(res, planes);
    magnitude(planes[0], planes[1], planes[0]);
    Mat mag = planes[0];
    mag += Scalar::all(1);
    log(mag, mag);
    mag = mag(Rect(0, 0, mag.cols & -2, mag.rows & -2));
    normalize(mag, mag, 1, 0, CV_MINMAX);

Comment: the result comes like this http://oi40.tinypic.com/jshvdu.jpg kindly help me , i have spent several hours and still no success....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a few problems going on here.

First, you need to use the [mulSpectrums](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=mulspectrums#void%20mulSpectrums%28InputArray%20src1,%20InputArray%20src2,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20flags,%20bool%20conj%29) function to convolve two FFTs, and **not** [multiply](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=multiply#multiply).

Second, the `createGaussianHighPassFilter` is only outputting a single channel non-complex filter. You'll probably need to just set the complex channel to `Mat::zeros` like you did for your input image.

Third, don't convert the output of the FFT to log-magnitude spectrum. It will not combine correctly with the filter, and you won't get the same thing when performing the inverse. So, just return `complexImg` right after the DFT is executed. Log-magnitude spectrum is useful for a human to look at the data, but not for what you are trying to do.

Finally, make sure you pay attention to the difference to between the full-complex output of `dft` and the Complex Conjugate Symmetric (CCS) packed output. Intel has a good page on how this data is formatted [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/504243). In your case, for simplicity I would keep everything in full-complex mode to make your life easier.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thankssss a lot mevatron your experience is great ..i have followed your advice and i first changed the single channel filter function createGaussianHighPassFilter into multi channel using below code ..... 
normalize(ghpf, ghpf, 0, 1, CV_MINMAX);
Mat padded;
copyMakeBorder(ghpf, padded, 0, size.height - ghpf.rows, 0, size.width - ghpf.cols, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar::all(0)); 
Mat planes[] = {Mat_<float>(padded), Mat::zeros(padded.size(), CV_32F)};
Mat complexImg;
merge(planes, 2, complexImg); return complexImg;

Comment: after that i have used cv::mulSpectrums(fft,ghpf,res,DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);
idft(res,res,DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT,img.rows);
 On the result that came I have used threshold to see the edges of finger ... I have tried log and without log result for it and it gives same result in threshold for both... Once again thank you so much and kindly correct me if i have still done any mistake above or now i am good to go (just for the sake of optimization)...  :)

Comment: Very cool :) For the sake of others interested, could you edit your question with the updated code? Glad to hear things are working out!

Comment: The above link to Intels explanation of the Complex Conjugate Symmetric output format is broken. Here's a new one: [packed format explanation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/504243).